# Apologize for misunderstanding

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style

My English not very good, especially if I have to comply some formal standards. I understand it pretty well, but when I have to construct a sentence I face some difficulties.

So I will try to explain the situation.
My boss and me changed some emails. I the last email-reply from him I received, it seems to me that he felt my writings somehow keen.

> so it seems we got a conflict of views of some kind. Which happens sometimes; please don't interpret it as a pressure. OK, we all are under some pressure from the Clients :) which I can't deny and which affects our workflow.

And now I want to apologize if I sounded somehow keen or intending to assert my point of view over his. Some ideas come to my mind, but my gut-feelings are telling me they are not good.

I was thinking about:

> I am sorry if I sounded as if I have problems with your advises

or

> I wanted by no means to sound like I have some sort of conflict with you.

To me these ^^^ sound not good. Some help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are well on the way. Since you ask I will add a few corrections.

To start I will say that you have *Ex*changed some emails with your boss. My basic advice is to say things as simply as you can. The more words you and your boss use the further they get from the goal.

I am sorry if I sounded as if I have problems with your advises [advice]

might be

I am sorry if I sounds like I have problems with your opinions.

or

I am sorry if it seems like I have problems with your opinions.

Best to make things in the present tense;
I wanted by no means to sound like I have some sort of conflict with you.

might be

I do not want to sound like I have some sort of conflict with you.
or

I would not want to sound like I have any conflict with you.